# Fractional parts of square roots of primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, radicals

To avoid confusion with other uses of braces, let $F:\Bbb R\to[0,1)$ be the fractional part function (usually noted as $\{\cdot\}$), so $F(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$.

It is known that the set $S:=\{F(\sqrt n):n\in\Bbb N\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$, because $S$ contains, for example, $\{F(n\sqrt 2):n\in\Bbb N\}$.

But is the set
$$\{F(\sqrt p):p\text{ prime}\}$$
also dense in $[0,1)$? I had been thinking on it, and my intuition says that it is, but I'm clueless about how to prove it. (In fact, I'm not sure even about the most appropriate tags for this question).

Answer (score 0):

For $\Re(z) > 0$ let $$g(z)=\sum_p e^{-p^{1/2}z} = \sum_{n \ge 2} \pi(n)(e^{-n^{1/2}z}-e^{-(n+1)^{1/2}z})=\sum_{n \ge 2} \frac{n}{\ln n}(1+o(1))e^{-n^{1/2}z} n^{-1/2}(1+o(1)) $$

The point is that for any fixed $y \ne 0$ then $$|g(x+2i\pi y)|\le g(x)  \qquad and \qquad g(x+2i\pi y) = o(g(x)) \qquad  as\quad x\to 0^+$$

For any $\phi(y) = \sum_k \hat{\phi}(k)e^{2i\pi k y}$ smooth $1$-periodic then

$$\boxed{\sum_p  e^{-p^{1/2}x} \phi(p^{1/2})= \sum_k g(x-2i\pi k)\hat{\phi}(k) = \hat{\phi}(0) g(x)+o(g(x))}$$

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question.

Comment: I'm sure you do take $\phi$ indicating a small part of $\Bbb{R/Z}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't have the knowledge to understand it.

Comment: Which part ? Take $\phi \ge 0$ supported on $[a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon]$, if $\{ p^{1/2}\} $ is never in $[a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon]$ then $\sum_p  e^{-p^{1/2}x} \phi(p^{1/2})=0$, which I showed is not the case. What I showed is that a proportion $2\epsilon$ of the primes is such that $\{ p^{1/2}\}\in [a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon]$.